# Phoenix Framework: why mix ecto.create and mix phx.server not working?

Tags: postgresql, phoenix-framework

I'm installing phoenix framework in windows 10 and I already create an application "project". I got an error when I type mix ecto.create and mix phx.server. Can someone help me to fix this problem? Thank you.

an error occurred in mix ecto.create

```
[error] GenServer #PID<0.318.0> terminating ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:163: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2 (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5 (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3 Last message: nil State: Postgrex.Protocol** (Mix) The database for Project.Repo couldn't be created: an exception was raised:/* (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused( db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:163: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2 (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5 (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

an error occurred in mix phx.server

```
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Plug.Cowboy.child_spec/1 is undefined (module Plug.Cowboy is not available)
            Plug.Cowboy.child_spec([scheme: :http, plug: {ProjectWeb.Endpoint, []}, options: [dispatch: [_: [{"/phoenix/live_reload/socket/websocket", Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket, {Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, {ProjectWeb.Endpoint, Phoenix.LiveReloader.Socket, [path: "/websocket", serializer: [{Phoenix.Socket.V1.JSONSerializer, "~> 1.0.0"}, {Phoenix.Socket.V2.JSONSerializer, "~> 2.0.0"}], timeout: 60000, transport_log: false, compress: false]}}}, {"/socket/websocket", Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket, {Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, {ProjectWeb.Endpoint, ProjectWeb.UserSocket, [path: "/websocket", serializer: [{Phoenix.Socket.V1.JSONSerializer, "~> 1.0.0"}, {Phoenix.Socket.V2.JSONSerializer, "~> 2.0.0"}], timeout: 60000, transport_log: false, compress: false]}}}, {:_, Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler, {ProjectWeb.Endpoint, []}}]], port: 4000, otp_app: :project]])
            (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy_adapter.ex:96: Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyAdapter.child_spec/3
            (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/supervisor.ex:111: anonymous fn/6 in Phoenix.Endpoint.Supervisor.server_children/4
            (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1940: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
            (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/supervisor.ex:102: Phoenix.Endpoint.Supervisor.server_children/4
            (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/supervisor.ex:67: Phoenix.Endpoint.Supervisor.init/1
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:295: :supervisor.init/1
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:374: :gen_server.init_it/2
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:342: :gen_server.init_it/6
            (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
** (Mix) Could not start application project: Project.Application.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: ProjectWeb.Endpoint
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Plug.Cowboy.child_spec/1 is undefined (module Plug.Cowboy is not available)
            Plug.Cowboy.child_spec([scheme: :http, plug: {ProjectWeb.Endpoint, []}, options: [dispatch: [_: [{"/phoenix/live_reload/socket/websocket", Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket, {Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, {ProjectWeb.Endpoint, Phoenix.LiveReloader.Socket, [path: "/websocket", serializer: [{Phoenix.Socket.V1.JSONSerializer, "~> 1.0.0"}, {Phoenix.Socket.V2.JSONSerializer, "~> 2.0.0"}], timeout: 60000, transport_log: false, compress: false]}}}, {"/socket/websocket", Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyWebSocket, {Phoenix.Transports.WebSocket, {ProjectWeb.Endpoint, ProjectWeb.UserSocket, [path: "/websocket", serializer: [{Phoenix.Socket.V1.JSONSerializer, "~> 1.0.0"}, {Phoenix.Socket.V2.JSONSerializer, "~> 2.0.0"}], timeout: 60000, transport_log: false, compress: false]}}}, {:_, Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler, {ProjectWeb.Endpoint, []}}]], port: 4000, otp_app: :project]])
            (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy_adapter.ex:96: Phoenix.Endpoint.CowboyAdapter.child_spec/3
            (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/supervisor.ex:111: anonymous fn/6 in Phoenix.Endpoint.Supervisor.server_children/4
            (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1940: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
            (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/supervisor.ex:102: Phoenix.Endpoint.Supervisor.server_children/4
            (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/supervisor.ex:67: Phoenix.Endpoint.Supervisor.init/1
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:295: :supervisor.init/1
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:374: :gen_server.init_it/2
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:342: :gen_server.init_it/6
            (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

I expect the output Phoenix framework welcome page in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The first message says that your application cannot connect to the database. I assume (based on the port) that you're using PostgreSQL. In that case, you need to ensure that you have PostgreSQL server installed and running on your computer (you'll find installation instructions here: https://www.postgresql.org/download/)

Regarding the 2nd message, this issue has been mentioned on Phoenix Github issues, you can find it here: https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/issues/3113. The solutions that are mentioned there include:
1. Updating Phoenix version (the error should be solved in v1.4.0, check what version you have in your `mix.exs` file)
2. Adding `:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.0"` to your list of dependencies (make sure to run `mix deps.get` after that)

Comment: I got an error when I type this `cd project && mix phx.server`
 it says: ** (File.Error) could not remove files and directories recursively not owner 
(elixir) lib/file.ex:1252: File.rm_rf!/1
(mix) lib/mix/tasks/deps.compile.ex:66: anonymous fn/4 in Mix.Tasks.Deps.Compile.compile/2

Comment: I already do the instruction that you gave, and I encounter new error.

Comment: My suggestion would be to update the Phoenix installer, update your Elixir, and start a new application from scratch. It seems you have incompatible versions which put your app in a bad state, sorry.